# jquery ajax: redirect with json - unexplainable behaviour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, debugging, redirect

I'm getting a json object from the server. If the json object has "redirect" as its status i'm calling a function to reload a little part of the page and then redirect to the jsonObject data value that contains a link I can redirect to.

```
$.ajax({
    url: loadUrl,
    dataType: "text json",
    success: function( jsonObject, status ) {

        if ( jsonObject.status == "redirect" ) {

            ajaxLoad($('.list'), $('.group').data('ajax-link'));

            location.href = jsonObject.data;

            return false;
        }

        …
```

and this is the ajaxLoad() function I'm calling that simply reloads a specific part of a page.

```
function ajaxLoad(targetBox, loadUrl) {

    $.ajax({
        url: loadUrl,
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 5000,
        cache: false,
        success: function( html, status ) {
            targetBox.html(html);
                    console.log("function() ajaxLoad : " + status);
        },
        error: function( request, status ) {
            console.log("function() ajaxLoad : " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

The weird thing is that if I comment out the `location.href = jsonObject.data` line the ajaxLoad() function logs SUCCESS, if i leave the redirect line the ajaxLoad() function logs ERROR. So if I leave the line the ajaxLoad function doesn't work, if I remove the line it works.

However, what has this line to do with rest of the script?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it the case that directing away from the current web page is cancelling your AJAX call.  Why not perform the redirect after the AJAX function completes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect you want to use `window.location = jsonObject.data;`

I would recommend putting the redirect inside a callback which you provide to `ajaxLoad` so the redirect happens on success of THAT ajax call. Then it won't be a race.

```
// Call ajaxLoad with the callback
ajaxLoad($('.list'), $('.group').data('ajax-link'), function(){window.location = jsonObject.data;});

// Add the callback to ajaxLoad
function ajaxLoad(targetBox, loadUrl, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        url: loadUrl,
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 5000,
        cache: false,
        success: function( html, status ) {
            targetBox.html(html);
                    console.log("function() ajaxLoad : " + status);

            if(typeof(callback) == 'function')
            {
                // Execute the redirect here
                callback();
            }
        },
        error: function( request, status ) {
            console.log("function() ajaxLoad : " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling ajaxLoad function asynchornously, before its resposnse comes location has changed so you will not see the expected bejavior. Try to set the location in the success handler of ajaxLoad. But I dont understand what is the use of ajaxLoad which partially updates the page and immediately changes the location.

```
if ( jsonObject.status == "redirect" ) {

            ajaxLoad($('.list'), $('.group').data('ajax-link'), jsonObject.data);

            return false;
        }


function ajaxLoad(targetBox, loadUrl, dataUrl) {

    $.ajax({
        url: loadUrl,
        dataType: "html",
        timeout: 5000,
        cache: false,
        success: function( html, status ) {
            targetBox.html(html);
                    console.log("function() ajaxLoad : " + status);

           location.href = dataUrl;
        },
        error: function( request, status ) {
            console.log("function() ajaxLoad : " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is bad programming practice. You should abstract the logic of the redirect into another function so ajaxLoad can be called without redirecting every time.

Comment: @Matt - The question was about why it was behaving weird. Yes offcourse we can create a callback method and redirect it in that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code is not executing in the order that you think that it does. The `ajaxLoad` function doesn't wait for the request to complete before it exists, it just sends the request and returns right away.

If you want the redirect to happen after the content is loaded, you have to do it from the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
  url: loadUrl,
  dataType: "text json",
  success: function( jsonObject, status ) {

    if ( jsonObject.status == "redirect" ) {

        ajaxLoad($('.list'), $('.group').data('ajax-link'), jsonObject.data);
        return false;
    }

...
```

and:

```
function ajaxLoad(targetBox, loadUrl, redirect) {

  $.ajax({
    url: loadUrl,
    dataType: "html",
    timeout: 5000,
    cache: false,
    success: function( html, status ) {
        targetBox.html(html);
        console.log("function() ajaxLoad : " + status);
        window.location.href = redirect;
    },
    error: function( request, status ) {
        console.log("function() ajaxLoad : " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I extend my same suggestion to you Guffa. Why force ajaxLoad to redirect every time it is called?

Comment: @Matt Anderson: Why not? Why force ajaxLoad to make a request every time it is called?